# Delete within a Range, without deleting on Sheet

Tags: excel, copy, range, vba

I apologize for the poor question name, if anybody has better suggestions at the end of this, let me know.

I have a range, say A1:M4 with the months in row 1 and a total for each row in column M. For each cell, there are values except for the months that have not yet happened. So if in November, everything up to November is filled in and December, column L, is empty and column M has the total from Jan to Nov (col A to col L). Another example, if in May, Jan, Feb, March, April and May and filled in, but not the other months, and column M has the total.

I want to create code that copies all the values up to the current month including the total for each row and paste into a powerpoint (I know how to copy and paste into a ppt). How do I copy this?

Current code:

```
rng=Range("a1",Range("a1").End(xldown).End(xlright))
```

Copies the entire range. How do I delete the columns without values in it. I thought of creating a count to count the values from column A to L, but having trouble incorporating how to remove the difference between total columns and filled in columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This procedure can help you to find empty columns.

```
Sub FindBlankColumns()
'Step1:  Declare your variables.
    Dim MyRange As Range
    Dim iCounter As Long
'Step 2:  Define the target Range. Change to fit your needs
    Set MyRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

'Step 3:  Start reverse looping through the range.
'You can modify this according to your needs.
    For iCounter = MyRange.Columns.Count To 1 Step -1

'Step 4: If entire column is empty then do some stuff.
       If Application.CountA(Columns(iCounter).EntireColumn) = 0 Then

          ' Insert your code here to do what you want with empty column.

       End If
    Next
End Sub
```